# I'm not able to get font-face working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm not able to get `font-face` working (That's why I usually use Google fonts). But a customer has their own font that I must use.

I'm testing and comparing against **[this site](http://www.cphvision.dk/)** (Main menu)

Here is my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jMN3/1/)**

Why am I not able to get this work? The font on the other website is working just fine.

Here's my CSS:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'testFont';
  src:url('http://www.cphvision.dk/sites/all/themes/vision/webfonts/21B1BE_0_0.eot');
  src:url('http://www.cphvision.dk/sites/all/themes/vision/webfonts/21B1BE_0_0.ttf'), format('truetype');
}

ul li a {
font-family:'testFont', sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

I've also tested on my local server. Not working there either.
I have previously tested using font-face on downloaded fonts from Google. No success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had issues with font-face before, as well. I know that when I have used it I did not surround the font-family attribute with quotes (single or double). Also, for some reason there seems to have been some sort of conflict with putting the font-face rules in the main style sheet so I put them in a separate style sheet and put this at the top of my main stylesheet:

```
@import url('font.css');
```

Here is a quick example of one of my instances of this rule, copied directly from the file:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: Kalinga;
  src:url(kalinga.ttf);
}

@font-face{
  font-family: Kalinga;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url(kalingab.ttf);
}
```

I know that I did not add both the ttf and the eot here, but it's a good example for you to refer to. I would recommend starting with either eot or ttf and getting one working and then adding the other when you're done (less changes to make when tinkering).

Comment: hmm... testing @nick-beranek's Font Squirrel, I downloaded a package. Opening the text html, the fonts work. But when I put it in to my WP solution, it's not working :( I've tried removing my otehr fonts and just have these new ones, but it doesn't help....

Comment: This did not solve my problem, but accepting the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend using a service like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). I say this because you can upload a font and it will automagically convert it to `eot`, `ttf`, etc, and provide you with a zip file containing your fonts and some sample files to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds crazy, but I have had trouble getting @font-face working with absolute paths. However I use it all the time with relative paths and it works fine. And I also recommend [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com). All you need to do is adjust the CSS path relative to where your fonts are from their provided generated kits and code. And of course with Worpress, always use a Child Theme to circumvent default font declarations.